# нужно чтобы рекорд сохранялся если он больше уже набранного

Tags: c#, unity3d

Нужно чтобы рекорд сохранялся если он больше уже набранного

```
using System.Collections;   
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using UnityEngine;
  using UnityEngine.UI;

 public class Score : MonoBehaviour                                

{     

private int Score_Player;
public Text txt;

void Start()   
{
    Score_Player = 1;
}

     public void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
    {
          if (col.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")  

    {   
            txt.text = "Рекорд : " + Score_Player;  
            Score_Player++;     //не знаю какое добавить условие   
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("RECORD", Score_Player);   
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Если вы не стараетесь даже отформатировать вопрос (я уже не говорю про то, чтобы удалить из него лишнее), зачем кому то стараться вам помогать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При старте получайте и запоминайте текущий рекорд. При увеличении кол-ва очков - сравнивайте старый рекорд и текущее кол-во очков. Если старый рекорд меньше - приравниваете его кол-ву очков и записываете новое значение.

```
public class Score : MonoBehaviour
{
    int _currentRecord = 0;
    private int Score_Player;
    public Text txt;

    void Start()
    {
        Score_Player = 1;
        _currentRecord = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("RECORD");
    }

    public void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
        {
            txt.text = "Рекорд : " + Score_Player;
            Score_Player++;
            if (_currentRecord < Score_Player)
            {
                _currentRecord = Score_Player;
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("RECORD", Score_Player);
            }
        }
    }
}
```